# Subclass a Django ManyRelatedManager a.k.a. ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to *Subclass a Django ManyRelatedManager a.k.a. ManyToManyField* ?

The goal is to pre-filter all related models when calling the `ManyRelatedManager` by a flag of `deleted=None`.  If `deleted=None` then it is a valid `Model`.

So far, this is the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class ExcludeDeletedManyToManyField(models.ManyToManyField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ExcludeDeletedManyToManyField, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(deleted__isnull=True)


class SelfRefrencingModel(models.Model):

    children = ExcludeDeletedManyToManyField('self', blank=True,
        symmetrical=False, related_name='parents')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) of `SelfRefrencingModel` and override the default [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets). Then use this proxy model in `ManyToManyField`.

Subclassing `ManyToManyField` will not help you because for the resulting queryset `ManyRelatedManger` is responsible.

Proxy model approach:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField('AProxy')
    name = models.TextField()
    deleted = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)


class FilterDeletedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FilterDeletedManager, self).get_query_set()
        return qs.filter(deleted__isnull=True)


class AProxy(A):
    objects = FilterDeletedManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Caveat with this approach is that now django expects `AProxy` instances for `children` field.

So maybe better readable and maintainable approach will be to add another attribute in `__init__`.

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    name = models.TextField()
    deleted = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.deleted_null_children = self.children.filter(deleted__isnull=True)
```

Comment: `Proxy Models` are for defining extra behavior on a model, and don't have any fields.  I don't think this will work.... Do you have a code example of getting this to work?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on either Django 1.9 or Django 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  @beezz, you may be correct to use a Proxy Model to do this, but I haven't used a Proxy Model before for this pattern, so this is how I solved this:

```
class SelfRefrencingQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    pass

class SelfRefrencingManager(BaseManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SelfRefrencingQuerySet(self.model, self._db).filter(
            deleted__isnull=True)

class SelfRefrencingBaseModel(models.Model):

    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False,
        related_name='parents')

    # Manager
    objects = SelfRefrencingManager()
    objects_all = models.Manager()     # So you still have acccess to the
                                       # default Manager
```

Comment: But with overriding default manager there's no way of getting models with `deleted__isnull=False`. Not only for field `children` but at all.

Comment: @beezz the same would go for overriding the `ManyToMany` field to exlude them right?  With my solution, you can still keep the default `models.Manager` and let the `Model` have 2 managers.  That's the pattern I'm using. 99% of the time we won't want the deleted records, so this pattern works good.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If your intention is to use this with Django Admin or `ModelForm`; you don't need to subclass the `ManyToManyField`. See the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to)

```
class SelfRefrencingModel(models.Model):

    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, 
        related_name='parents', limit_choices_to={'deleted': False}))
```

**Note:** If `deleted` is a `BooleanField` it has to be `True` or `False`. It can't be `None`/`NULL`.

**beezz's** idea of using a Proxy Model is also a good one.

What I sometimes do is to customise the default manager

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(deleted=False)


class MyModelManager(models.Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()
    _objects = models.Manger()

    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

By default `deleted` objects will be hidden, but if need them in your queryset, you can use `_objects`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `limit_choices_to` argument. As described in django's documentation it works only for admin and `ModelForm` but maybe that's the case here.

Comment: I could not get the `limit_choices_to` to work when calling `model.children.all()` for example.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include your observations.