# How can I override user.groups in a custom account model in Django to implement a "virtual" group?

Tags: django

I have a custom account class in a Django app using PermissionsMixin:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

Our CMS calls various .groups methods on this class in order to ascertain permissions.

We essentially want to override the queryset that is returned from .groups in this custom Account class and to inject an additional group under specific conditions. (I.e. the user has an active subscription and we then want to return "member" as one of the groups for that user, despite them not actually being in the group.)

How should we handle this override? We need to get the original groups, so that basic group functionality isn't broken, then inject our "virtual" group into the queryset.

Comment: I gather that I may need to use a manager of some kind to do this. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: ... Or is this only possible via some horrible monkey patch?

Comment: `groups` is `ManyToManyField`. You don't want to use `ManyToManyField`? Or You want to use `ManyToManyField` with your `virtual groups`? Why you don't add your `virtual` group rows in `Group`

Answer (score 8):

Override the `get_queryset` method `ManyRelatedManager`. An object of `ManyRelatedManager` class has access to the parent instance.

Code Sample:

```
def add_custom_queryset_to_many_related_manager(many_related_manage_cls):
    class ExtendedManyRelatedManager(many_related_manage_cls):
        def get_queryset(self):
            qs = super(ExtendedManyRelatedManager, self).get_queryset()
            # some condition based on the instance
            if self.instance.is_staff:
                return qs.union(Group.objects.filter(name='Gold Subscription'))
            return qs

    return ExtendedManyRelatedManager
```

> `ManyRelatedManager` class is obtained from the
>   `ManyToManyDescriptor`.

```
class ExtendedManyToManyDescriptor(ManyToManyDescriptor):

    @cached_property
    def related_manager_cls(self):
        model = self.rel.related_model if self.reverse else self.rel.model
        return add_custom_queryset_to_many_related_manager(create_forward_many_to_many_manager(
            model._default_manager.__class__,
            self.rel,
            reverse=self.reverse,
        ))
```

> Associated the `ExtendedManyToManyDescriptor` with `groups` field when
>   the `Account` class is initialized.

```
class ExtendedManyToManyField(ManyToManyField):

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedManyToManyField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, self.name, ExtendedManyToManyDescriptor(self.remote_field, reverse=False))
```

> Override `PermissionsMixin` to use `ExtendedManyToManyField` for
>   `groups` field instead of `ManyToManyField`.

```
class ExtendedPermissionsMixin(PermissionsMixin):
    groups = ExtendedManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Reference:
`django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager`

Testing:

```
account = Account.objects.get(id=1)
account.is_staff = True
account.save()

account.groups.all() 

# output
[<Group: Gold Subscription>]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update

After reading carefully the docs related to Managers and think about your requirement, I've to say there is no way to achieve the magic you want (*I need to override the original, not to add a new ext_groups set - I need to alter third party library behavior that is calling groups.*) Without touch the Django core itself (monkey patching would mess up admin, the same with properties).

In the solution I'm proposing, you have the necessary to add a new manager to `Group`, perhaps, you should start thinking in override that third-party library you're using, and make it use the Group's Manager you're interested in.

If the third-party library is at least medium quality it will have implemented tests that will help you to keep it working after the changes.

### Proposed solution

Well, the good news is you can fulfill your business requirements, the bad news is you will have code a little more than you surely expect.

*How should we handle this override?*

You could use a proxy model to the `Group` class in order to add a custom manager that returns the desired QuerySet.

A proxy manager won't add an extra table for groups and will keep all the `Group` functionality besides, you can set custom managers on proxy models too, so, its perfect for this case use.

```
class ExtendedGroupManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        # Do work with qs.
        return qs


class ExtendedGroup(Group):
    objects = ExtendedGroupManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then your `Account` class should then have a `ManyToMany` relationship to `ExtendedGroup` that can be called ...  ext_groups?

Till now you can:

```
acc = Account(...)
acc.groups.all()      # All groups for this account (Django default).
acc.ext_groups.all()  # Same as above, plus any modification you have done in get_queryset  method.
```

Then, in views, you can decide if you call one or another depending on a condition of your own selection (Eg. user is subscribed).

Is worth mention you can add a custom manager to an existeing model using the method `contribute_to_class`

```
em = ExtendGroupManager()
em.contribute_to_class(Group, 'ext_group')

# Group.ext_group  is now available.
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is that I need to override the original, not to add a new ext_groups set - I need to alter third party library behaviour that is calling groups.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I will give it a try today

Answer (score 2):

The `groups` related manager is added by the `PermissionMixin`, you could actually remove the mixin and add only the parts of it that you need and redefine `groups`:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    # add the fields like is_superuser etc...
    # as defined in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L200

    default_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    @property
    def groups(self):
        if self.is_subscribed:
            return Group.objects.filter(name="subscribers")
        return default_groups.all()
```

Then you can add your custom groups using the `Group` model. This approach should work fine as long it is ok for all parts that `groups` returns a queryset instead of a manager (which probably mostly should be fine as managers mostly offer the same methods - but you probably need to find out yourself).

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS calls Account.groups directly I would investigate how to override a ManyRelatedManager since the account.groups is actually a django ManyRelatedManager object.

It can probably be achieved using django [Proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for the Group.

One strategy to investigate would then be:

- Add the virtual group to the groups in the database.
- Override the ManyRelatedManager by changing get_queryset() (The base queryset)

Something like (pseudo code):

```
def get_queryset():
   account = self.instance # Guess this exist in a RelatedManager
   if account.has_active_subscribtion():
     return self.get_all_relevant_groups_including_the_virtual_one()
   return self.get_all_relevant_groups_excluding_the_virtual_one()
```

The key here is to get access to the current instance in the custom RelatedManager

This may be a useful discussion around custom related managers.
[Subclass a Django ManyRelatedManager a.k.a. ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32259010/1714030)

I do not recommend to try fiddle/monkey patch with the queryset itself since it very easy to break the django admin etc...